# Failing to Redirect Subdomain with Route 53 to Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, subdomain, amazon-route53

Aim: To set-up a subdomain that redirects to an elastic beanstalk instance

I recently bought a domain (tscthub.co.uk) from GoDaddy, transferred it over to 'AWS Route 53' via GANDI, and am waiting on SSL to be approved via 'AWS Certificate Manager'.

Separately I created an 'AWS Elastic Beanstalk' application running Metabase using [this guide](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/running-metabase-on-elastic-beanstalk.html). This is up and running and I can successfully access it. Whilst the metabase [env url](http://metabase-env.eba-i2ysq7n4.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/) works nicely, the [public IPv4 address](https://13.40.164.101/) and [public IPv4 DNS](https://ec2-13-40-164-101.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/) don't load anything when I follow them.

Next I tried to follow the ["Routing traffic to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html) guide on the AWS docs. In 'AWS Route 53' I first created a new public hosted zone for 'tscthub.co.uk'. I edited the named servers in the registered domain to match that of the hosted zone. Then because my 'AWS Elastic Beanstalk' environment url had the region within it I thought I could use an alias as per the guide, however, upon trying I got the error *"an alias to another record in the same hosted zone are global and available only in US East (N. Virginia)"* and unfortunately I'm using 'eu-west-2' ([this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/nwvphm/comment/h1mbvxy/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) talks about this issue in more detail).

I therefore just used the backfall approach of creating a new CNAME record where the record name was 'test.tscthub.co.uk' and the value was 'http://metabase-env.eba-i2ysq7n4.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/'. After waiting a couple of hours for everything to reroute I then tried to access 'http://test.tscthub.co.uk/' but I just get "This site can’t be reached".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that what the ["Routing traffic to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html) guide fails to mention is that you can just create an "A" record and set that to the elastic beanstalk environment ...